# REPL using IMain, Akka and sbt: get import working

Tags: scala, sbt, interpreter

I'm trying to get an interactive shell into my Scala application. I'm using the following system:

- Scala 2.10.0
- sbt 0.12.2
- Akka 2.1.0
- sbt-lwjgl-plugin 3.1.4

and the following non-working code:

```scala
    import akka.actor.Actor
    import scala.tools.nsc.Settings
    import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain

    class TestActor extends Actor {
      def receive => {
        case _ => {
          val settings = new Settings
          settings.usejavacp.value = true
          settings embeddedDefaults ActorSystem.getClass.getClassLoader
          val repl = new IMain(settings)
          repl.interpret("import java._")               // working
          repl.interpret("import scala._")              // working
          repl.interpret("import akka._")               // not working
          repl.interpret("import other.java.class.Bar") // not working
        }
      }
    }
```

Sbt is set to `fork := true`. I've tried several settings and class path configurations, but didn't find a working configuration. Can someone give me a hint/solution for this problem?

Comment: This problem arises when running the application from `sbt`. I don't know how to fix this, but you could use `sbt-assembly` to create a self-contained jar, and run that directly outside of `sbt`, that will work.

Comment: Also perhaps [this plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script) if you need to run often and don't want to waste time to repackage jars all the time.

Comment: OK, both methods are working. I prefer the first one, because it generates path and platform independent results. Some extra code was required to get lwjgl running. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to re-import all classpath with absolute path?

```
val settings = new Settings
settings.usejavacp.value = true

val classLoader = Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader

classLoader.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader].getURLs.map(url => new File(url.toURI).getAbsolutePath).foreach {
  jarPath =>
    println(s"adding into Scala SDK classpath : ${jarPath}")

    settings.bootclasspath.append(jarPath)
    settings.classpath.append(jarPath)
}
```